# Scalar multiplication of matrix (int is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, subscript

Question:
You are given a M∗N matrix, and a variable K, print the resultant matrix after scalar multiplication.
Code i have written:

```
n,m,k=map(int,input().split())
mat1=[]
for i in range(n):
    mat1.append(list(map(int,input().split())))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        mat1=mat1[i][j] * k
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(mat1[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/91934/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    mat1=mat1[i][j] * k
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the list variable `mat1` with a number value with this line, resulting in the said error:

```
mat1=mat1[i][j] * k
```

Instead, you should specify the nested list item that is to be assigned by index:

```
mat1[i][k] = mat1[i][j] * k
```

or:

```
mat1[i][j] *= k
```